# How to use unique post data in a variable for login case using jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have found so many solutions for extracting data for jmeter using Regular Expression Extractor, but none of those are helping me.

I need to use the values of x and y from below image and set it to variables for next usage. 
[image]

I have tried with following regular Expression...
 for x, *&x=?y* and for y, *&y=?

Could some one from you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression: `x=(\w+)` and `y=(\w+)`

You can also use this one: `y=(\d*)`

Check the sample image below:

[image]

You can also check your test string [here](https://regex101.com/).